# Chappati flour (Indian store flour)

Tags: flour

Can someone elaborate on chappati flour from an Indian grocery store. Is it considered a hard wheat or soft wheat? And is it really whole wheat because it looks more like white flour to me. Could I use it for muffins or pancakes?

Comment: You will find enlightenment in the answer to this question: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/10157/using-chakki-atta-instead-of-whole-wheat-flour

Which, alas, means that your question is a duplicate.  Have fun baking!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Chakki Atta instead of whole wheat flour?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/10157/using-chakki-atta-instead-of-whole-wheat-flour)

Comment: @FuzzyChef: I know next to nothing about Indian food, but the question you link is about *chakki atta*, which based on the answers to that question is a different thing than *chappati atta*. It seems like *chakki atta* is coarsely ground, while *chappati atta* is finely ground.

Comment: Er .. no.  "Chakki" just refers to a finer grade -- it's properly stone-milled, whereas something marked "Chapati Atta" is the same wheat and flour, just hot roller milled so that it's drier and supposedly inferior.  It's like "cornmeal" vs. "stone-ground cornmeal".

Comment: Here's a link that talks about that: https://www.kannammacooks.com/why-my-atta-flour-doesnt-work-in-bread-loaves/

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand chappatti flour (atta) is very finely ground whole wheat flour, so it does appear to be more white than regular whole wheat flour, but it does have a noticable difference if you compare the two flours side by side, both in texture and colour.
You could definitely use it for muffins or pancakes if you're so inclined! Just as you can sub whole wheat flour, you could sub atta.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say whether chapatti atta is soft or hard wheat. Mainly because that kind of characterisation is not really done for this product. I would place it on par with whole wheat flour to the characteristics. For pancake it is ok, but for muffin it might be too tough. (Am Indian)